# Objective-C/cocoa's equivalent to Python's os.path.split() to get directory name and file name

Tags: python, objective-c, path

When I have a path, I can use os.path.split() in Python to get directory name, and file name.

```
>>> x = '/a/b/c/hello.txt'
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.split(x)
('/a/b/c', 'hello.txt')
```

What's the equivalent function in Objective-C/cocoa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easier way (well, than messing with subarrays); look in NSPathUtilities.h.

```
- (NSString *)lastPathComponent;
- (NSString *)stringByDeletingLastPathComponent;
- (NSString *)stringByAppendingPathComponent:(NSString *)str;

- (NSString *)pathExtension;
- (NSString *)stringByDeletingPathExtension;
- (NSString *)stringByAppendingPathExtension:(NSString *)str;

- (NSArray *)stringsByAppendingPaths:(NSArray *)paths;
```

Using the "/a/b/c/hello.txt" example:

```
 NSString *path = @"/a/b/c/hello.txt";

 NSString *fileName = [path lastPathComponent];
  // 'hello.txt'

 NSString *basePath = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
  // '/a/b/c'

 NSString *newPath = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"goodbye.txt"];
  // '/a/b/c/goodbye.txt'
```

And so on...

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *a = @"/a/b/c/hello.txt";
NSArray *path = [a pathComponents];
NSArray *startOfPath = [path subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [path count]-2)];
[NSString pathWithComponents:startOfPath]; // /a/b/c
[a lastPathComponent]; // hello.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't `[path subArrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [path count]-1)` just return `path`? Like, what items would not be included in that range?

Comment: Probably should be -2. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

NSString has - `(NSArray *)pathComponents`.