# Objective-C Split a String and get last item

Tags: objective-c

I have a string like so:

```
NSString *path = @"\\fake\aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd\eee.pdf";
```

and I split the string into an array like so:

```
 NSArray *array = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@"\"];
```

Now there are two things I need here.

1. I need a string with everything except eee.pdf
2. I need the last item in the array as a string (eee.pdf)

How would I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C/cocoa's equivalent to Python's os.path.split() to get directory name and file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138677/objective-c-cocoas-equivalent-to-pythons-os-path-split-to-get-directory-name)

Comment: Actually you could get unexpected results when using unescaped backslashes in literal strings.

Comment: Are you sure you mean '\' and not '/'? `/` is the path separator on OSX and iOS.

Comment: `NSString *path = @"\\fake\aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd\eee.pdf";` does not compile: `Unknown escape sequence '\c'`, `Unknown escape sequence '\d'`. In a literal string single back-slashes signal character escaping, you need double back-slashes if you want a single one in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun, there is a little-known way to get an `NSURL` with its benefit from a windows file path

```
NSString *path = @"\\\\fake\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\ddd\\eee.pdf";
NSURL *url = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)path, kCFURLWindowsPathStyle, false));
NSString *fileName = url.lastPathComponent;
NSString *parentDirectory = url.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent.path;
```

Finally you have to convert `parentDirectory` back to windows path style (backslashes).

But if you mean POSIX paths used in OS X, it's much easier

```
NSString *path = @"/fake/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee.pdf";
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSString *fileName = url.lastPathComponent;
NSString *parentDirectory = url.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent.path;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the last element use the `lastObject` property of the `NSArray`.

For a string without the last element use `subarrayWithRange:` using `array.count-1` for the `NSRange` length.

Then join the remaining array with `componentsJoinedByString:`.

```
NSString *fileName = [array lastObject];
NSArray  *newArray = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, array.count-1)];
NSString *directoryPath = [newArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\\"];
```

Comment: `arrayWithObjects:count:` works on a plain C array which is a bit difficult to use with ARC. You probably want to use `subarrayWithRange:` instead.

Comment: Yep, I see the fix is in. My fault, I usually check my code in Xcode but didn't here and got caught! Bad Zaph!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to get the filepath and filename from a full path. There are better ways of doing that. But since you simply asked for the question, here's my answer. Please note that this is not the best approach. In addition, you have to escape the backslashes by using a preceding backslash.

```
NSString *path = @"\\fake\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\ddd\\eee.pdf";
NSArray *array = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\"];

NSMutableArray *removedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i< array.count -1; i++){
    [removedArray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
}

NSString *joinedString =[removedArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\\"];
NSString *fileName = [array lastObject];

NSLog(@"Path: %@", joinedString);
NSLog(@"Filename: %@", fileName);
```